# Issue with JDK installation

Tags: java-8

I have install JDK 8 kit. 
I have set path variable to jdk bin

**D:\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin**

and home to jdk.

**D:\Java\jdk1.8.0_181**

I am able to see the version in cmd promt when I give **java -version**. But when I give **javac - version** its not able to find the jdk? Can anyone say what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

On windows after installation (if no other java's are there) it should work out of the box - if not you should set JAVA_HOME to D:\Java\jdk1.8.0_181 and add JAVA_HOME\bin to the path. If you do so you have to restart any already open commandline - because they will not get the JAVA_HOME/PATH updates (if you did them via the windows system control).

You could test what java -version tells you first - to find out if a runtime environment is still referenced.

Comment: When I give Java -version I am getting

java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)

Comment: So you are still one the jre and not on the jdk. - Means no javac.

Comment: The JDK doesn’t care about a `JAVA_HOME` variable at all.

Comment: Maybe you have the jre earlier in the path variable?

Comment: Ok in that case what should I do?

Comment: You should make sure that there is only one jre or jdk in your PATH.